# SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL not updating value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a PostgreSQL table defined in my model class as:

```
    class Interruption(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tbl_interruptions"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    file_link = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text('Now()'))
    is_downloaded = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_extracted = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

The create & get queries are working fine but updates don't work. When I try to update the `is_downloaded` column it doesn't work. The query returns `1` meaning the action has been accomplished in the DB but the value doesn't update. Below is the update snippet:

```
def update_interruption_download_status(db: Session, status: bool, interruption_id: int):
    return (db.query(models.Interruption).filter(models.Interruption.id == interruption_id)
            .update({models.Interruption.is_downloaded: status}))
```

I've tried to change the column type to int but it still doesn't work. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Oopsies, I didn't know I had to commit. I just added `db.commit()` and now it works :-)